# AppFabric Dashboard Throwing Powershell Error

Tags: powershell, appfabric

I have installed AppFabric onto Server2012. I checked the prerequisites were installed first and have installed accumulative update 3. I have an instance of SQL Server 2012 installed to SP1 and the OS indicates that all updates have been installed.

When viewing the dashboard I am receiving the error:

> Unable to cast object to type
>   'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Management.Data.Group...'

I've found minimal information during my google searches, none of which are providing a solution to the problem.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found that applying Windows Update [KB2932678](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2932678/cumulative-update-package-5-for-microsoft-appfabric-1.1-for-windows-server) (Cumulative update package 5 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server) stopped the error from coming up.

EDIT : [KB3092423](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3092423/cumulative-update-7-for-microsoft-appfabric-1.1-for-windows-server) (Cumulative Update 7) is the latest one I could find, so if you are going to apply an update you might as well apply the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. I read somewhere (don't have the link) that it appears because there are no records in the AppFabric Monitoring DB's table that contains the instances (of the service).

Once you have at least one record there, the error will disappear and the Dashboard will show the WF instances correctly.

This worked in my case.

UPDATE:

To be precise, the table which is relevant for the AppFabric Dashboard to stop showing the aforementioned error is: AppFabric Persistence DB's table [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable] . This table should contain at least one record that is related to the WF Service(s) that the current AppFabric Dashboard is shown for.